# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Confusion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

Here is my situation;

- I have an agreements table which will list the different types of agreements there are. It's a lookup table basically.
- I have a client_agreements table which list which clients have signed up to which type of agreement. I have an `agreement_id` within this table (foreign key id).

As I am using Laravel, here is my Controller method to view all agreements for a specific client;

```
public function index($client_id)
{
    $client_agreements = Agreement::find($client_id);

    return View::make('client_agreements.index')
        ->with('client_agreements', $client_agreements);
}
```

Here is my `Agreement` Model;

```
class Agreement extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'agreements';

    public function client_agreements(){

        return $this->hasMany('ClientAgreement', 'agreement_id');
    }

}
```

So I want to output in the view from the `agreements` table;

- agreement_type
- level

and from the `client_agreements` table;

- start_date
- expire_date

My View code (which I'm sure is wrong but don't know why) is essentially;

```
@foreach($client_agreements as $client_agreement)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->agreement_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->level }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->start_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->expire_date }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$client = Client::with('agreements')->find($client_id);
$client_agreements = $client->agreements;
return View::make('client_agreements.index')
           ->with('client_agreements', $client_agreements);
```

And in your view:

```
@foreach($client_agreements as $client_agreement)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->agreement_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->level }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->pivot->start_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client_agreement->pivot->expire_date }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This would require the following setup:

#### Client model

```
class Client extends Eloquent {

    public function agreements(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Agreement', 'client_agreements')->withPivot('id', 'start_date', 'expire_date');
    }
}
```

#### Agreement model

```
class Agreement extends Eloquent {

    public function clients(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'client_agreements')->withPivot('id', 'start_date', 'expire_date');
    }
}
```

For more information read the [Eloquent docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) (especially the section about relationships)

Comment: I actually already have a Client model - or maybe you just figured out that I probably would. Your solution works, so thank you! Can you explain why I have to involve the Client model/class here though? I can't quite visualise it.. even after reading the docs.

Comment: Well you have to involve the Client model anyway. You can try to fetch all agreements that have a relation with the Client with `$client_id` but that makes it more complicated to access the pivot data. I'll always "start" at the entity I have the id from in such cases... You know what I mean?

Comment: I would never have thought to include the Client model at this point so looks like I have more reading to do. Do you know how I can display the `client_agreements.id` value? If I do `$client_agreement->id` in the view then that just displays the `agreements.id` value..

Comment: Try `$client_agreement->pivot->id` if that doesn't work you need to add `id` to the `withPivot` call in the relation. I know that both foreign keys (`client_id` and `agreement_id`) are automatically available in the `pivot` object but I'm not sure about the id itself...

Comment: I had to add `id` to the relation but then it did work.. Thanks.